# Limit sql azure access from an azure web app

Tags: sql-server, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

How can I limit the permissions of an Azure SQL database when accessed from an Azure web app?

Details - I am working with an Azure SQL database and creating an ASP.NET Core web app. In the web app I have put a connection string that points to the Azure SQL database. The connection string includes the server admin username and password of the Azure SQL server. The web app successfully communicates with the database and can read and write data. Now, as a safety precaution, I would like to prevent the web app from ever deleting a database table (whether this be due to a mistake in the code, or a malicious SQL injection performed on the web app). How can I set permissions on the Azure SQL database to disallow table deletions from the web app?

I have heard of Azure Active Directory; I have never used it but I gather that it is an approach to manage identities and permissions of database users. Is there something similar to manage the permission of a web app rather than a user. Or is it possible to treat the web app as a user and assign user permissions/roles to it? If so, what would be the correct approach to implement this?

(Also, while we are on the subject, aside from preventing table deletions are there some other CRUD operations that you would recommend preventing from a security perspective as a best practice?)

Comment: A better approach would be to create a new SQL user account that only has the SQL permissions that your app needs.  Use this account in your app's connection string, instead of the admin account.  [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-database-user?view=sql-server-2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-database-user?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: I will look into this approach, thanks for the link. Is there a reason you consider it a better approach though? My concern is that since it requires sql commands to be run directly on the database, this new user account will not be reflected in the azure portal (unlike the sql server username and password), nor will the creation of the account be visible in the app code, and so it will be a bit of a mystery to any other developer who works on it the project.

Comment: As a general rule when applying security (and not just in the SQL world), it's best to grant only the permissions that are required to complete the needed task(s).  Because the more permissions you grant, the greater your exposure to risk.  i.e. if the user doesn't need to be able to perform action ABC, then don't grant them the ability to perform action ABC.  You can always grant additional permissions later, as required.

Comment: Also, you definitely don't want to make your SQL account credentials visible from anywhere in your app, so avoid keeping the login and password in the web.config or in the code.  By all means, though, provide documentation with your app that gives necessary details to help future developers understand how you’ve set up your security.

Comment: If you decide to go the SQL account route, then I recommend looking into using Azure KeyVault to store either the credentials, or the SQL connection string that contains those credentials.  You can set the connection string in each deployment slot from the Azure Portal, while viewing your app’s app service (Configuration section).  The values you set here will override the matching values in your web.config.

Comment: @DBro: Thank you for this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there something similar to manage the permission of a web app rather than a user.

Yes.  It's called Managed Identities. Azure will provision an identity in your Azure Active Directory, and ensure that only code running in your Application can generate tokens for that identity.  This gives you the ability to authenticate and connect to SQL Server (and other Azure Resources) without having a username/password or a client secret in your code or configuration.

See:
[Azure AD managed identities for Azure resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/)

> Managed identities for Azure resources provides Azure services with an
>   automatically managed identity in Azure Active Directory (Azure AD).
>   You can use this identity to authenticate to any service that supports
>   Azure AD authentication without having any credentials in your code.
>   Learn how to create and manage managed identities for Azure resources
>   with our quickstarts and tutorials.

And: [Tutorial: Secure Azure SQL Database connection from App Service using a managed identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-connect-msi)

> are there some other CRUD operations that you would recommend preventing from a security perspective as a best practice

You should create a database role that has the minimal permissions required to run the application, and add your application user(s) to that role.  The permissions needed will, of course, depend on what your application does, but the role might look something like this:

```
create role ApplicationUser

grant select,insert,update,delete,execute on schema::dbo to ApplicationUser

deny delete on AuditLog to ApplicationUser
```

(In SQL Server a DENY overrides any GRANTs and so you can grant permissions at the schema-level, and selectively DENY permissions at the object level)

Comment: David, this is good information, and it does answer my question. The other comments by DBro and and Leon suggest a different approach - create a contained database user in the SQL database which will authenticate using SQL server authentication, as opposed to your approach of creating an Azure Managed Identity which will authenticate through Azure Active Directory. Does Microsoft currently recommend one method over the other? Or list pros and cons somewhere? (Even in the SQL contained database user approach one can avoid the con of putting credentials in the app if one uses Azure Key store).

Comment: Yes Manged Identities are recommended, where applicable.  And  on " one can avoid the con of putting credentials in the app if one uses Azure Key store", then where do you store the credentials for the Key Vault?

Answer (score 1):

As Dbro said, we suggest you create a new login and user to limit the permissions of an Azure SQL database when accessed from an Azure web app.

Replace the app connection string with the new Non-administrator username and password.

And we all know, no matter which way we access or connect to the Azure SQL database, we must through the SQL account, Server administrator or new Non-administrator.

Different Azure SQL account has different permission on database operation CURD.

Fore more details, please reference Azure document [Controlling and granting database access to SQL Database and SQL Data Warehouse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-logins).

When a new user you created, you can decided which database permissions to grant for the user. Please see: [GRANT Database Permissions (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-database-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

For security, Azure also provides the Azure Key Vault for you. To see: [Always Encrypted: Protect sensitive data and store encryption keys in Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-always-encrypted-azure-key-vault):

**Summary:**

Always Encrypted is a new data encryption technology in Azure SQL Database and SQL Server that helps protect sensitive data at rest on the server, during movement between client and server, and while the data is in use. Always Encrypted ensures that sensitive data never appears as plaintext inside the database system. After you configure data encryption, only client applications or app servers that have access to the keys can access plaintext data.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Although I have accepted David Browne's answer as the correct one, since it is Microsoft's recommended approach within Azure, this answer is also a perfectly valid approach. +1.